# XCode accidently added my project to folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I accidentally added my project to a folder. How can I undo this? Here's the image describing what i have done:

[image]

Thanks.

UPDATE: I dragged it out, it asked me to save a new workspace (don't know what that means) and now it's fixed, but on top it looks like this:

[image]

Although it compiles/works fine, this isn't normal and bugging me. Please help.

Comment: I did. Please see my updated question again which describes what happened.

Comment: There's no description in this question which suggests how BoltClock might be wrong. ;)

Comment: @Jonathan: Now there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have replicated this.

Now that you have a new workspace:

- Drag your project out of the group ( folder )
- Quit Xcode
- Navigate to where the workspace and project are located
- Delete the workspace file ( .xcworkspace )
- Re-open Xcode by double clicking the project file ( .xcodeproj )

BTW, workspaces are pretty cool. You can nest multiple projects within a single workspace.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I did this, and after deleting the workspace file the "New Folder" is back (see first image in my question).

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to drag the project out of the group, while it is still in the workspace. Make sense?

Comment: I tried that and it moves out. Then it asks me to save it in a new workspace. I do that, then quit xcode, delete workspace, but when I reopen the project, everything is back to square 1.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you have encountered a bug. You might be better off just starting a completely new project, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same accidental situation.  When it creates the project workspace, it adds the "unititle" project workspace at the top level and an ADDITIONAL project workspace file within the project files. Delete both workspace files and the newgroup folder and restart xcode. Hopefully that works anyone in need.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To be more specific: quit XCode, right-click on the .xcodeproj > Show contents and delete the entire xcworkspace inside, and don't forget to delete the top-level workspace. Start XCode again - should be back to normal.   EDIT: turns out one file was not re-created: project.xcworkspace > xcuserdat > name.xcuserdata > WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings. Not that it's needed though. I got it back from version control.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while I happened to have git(version control system) enabled.
I tried to commit local changes, right clicked on the "workspace" file which by comparison you can see it's now under an "untitled" group, right clicked and reverted that file itself, and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this when I move my project from Dropbox to the local FS. Somehow all the files point to the local FS, but not the main top xcworkspace in XCode, that was still pointing to Dropbox.

So in XCode I change it's location in "Identity and Type" in the right pane, to the local project folder where the xcworkspace file was. This gave me the folder view in the top like you have.

I could only solve it by manually editing the contents.xcworkspacedata on the local FS;

location = "group:">

location = "group:/Users/rbollen/Downloads/myApp/myApp.xcodeproj">